# Return value of "==" operator in C

Tags: c

Can I assume that in C, the "==" operator will always evaluate to 1 if the two values are equal or it can evaluate to other "true" values?

```
struct ss {
    int id;
};

struct os {
    int sid;
    int state;
};

int count(struct ss *s, int state)
{
    int num = 0;
    // foreach o (of type os*) in a hash table
        num += o->state == state && (s ? o->sid == s->id : 1);

    return num;
}
```

So `o->sid == s->id` will return always 1 or 0, or it can return other values?

Comment: see http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9p3

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Can I assume that in C, the "==" operator will always evaluate to 1 if the two values are equal or it can evaluate to other "true" values?

Yes, and so does `!=` `>` `<` `>=` `<=` all the relational operator.

C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §6.5.8 *Relational operators*

> Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >=
>   (greater than or equal to) shall yield 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is
>   false.107) The result has type int.

Comment: It should be noted that C’s guarantee that the operators evaluate to 0 or 1 only holds in “normal” conditions. If a program contains any behavior described by the C standard as “undefined,” then it permits these operators (and any others) to produce any value at all (or other behaviors). For example, `a < b`, where `a` and `b` are pointers to unrelated objects, has behavior not defined by the C standard. This is useful to keep in mind for debugging: If one observes a program doing something “impossible” by the C standard, this is a clue that it may contain “undefined” behavior.

Answer (score 14):

From the standard :

> **6.5.8 Relational operators**
>
> Each of the operators < (less than), > (greater than), <= (less than or equal to), and >=
>   (greater than or equal to) shall yield **1** if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type **int**.
>
> **6.5.9 Equality operators**
>
> The **==** (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational
>   operators except for their lower precedence. **Each of the operators yields 1** if the
>   specified relation is true and 0 if it is false. The result has type **int**. For any pair of
>   operands, exactly one of the relations is true.

For logical operands (`&&`, `||` ) :

> **6.5.13 Logical AND operator ( or 6.5.14 Logical OR operator )**
>
> The **&&** (or **||**) operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

You can check the last draft here : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

**Conclusion :**

- All the equality and relational operator (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) return `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`.
- The logical operators (`==`, `||`, `!`) treat `0` as `false` and other values as `true` for their operands. They also return `0` as `false` and `1` as `true`.

Answer (score 10):

The comparison (equality and relational) operators (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) all return 0 for false and 1 for true — and no other values.

The logical operators `&&`, `||` and `!` are less fussy about their operands; they treat 0 as false and any non-zero value as true.  However, they also return only 0 for false and 1 for true.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I assume that in C, the "==" operator will always evaluate to 1 if the two values are equal or it can evaluate to other "true" values?

Yes, for a standard compliant compiler, this assumption is correct:

Programming languages — C, **§6.5.9 Equality operators** (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> Each of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0
>   if it is false. The result has type int.