# What happens when we arbitrarily use ==?

Tags: c, operators, logical-operators, relational

I tried running the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a = 10, b = 5, c = 5;
   int d;
   d = b + c == a;
   printf("%d", d);
}
```

I got the output as `d = 1`. Can someone please explain to me what happens when we use `==` like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "like this"? As opposed to using it how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the "true" result of >, <, !, &&, || or == defined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687403/is-the-true-result-of-or-defined)

Answer (score 1):

> §6.5.9 (== and !=)-http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.9.html
>
> The == (equal to) and != (not equal to) operators are analogous to the relational operators except for their lower precedence.)Each of the operators yields 1 if the specified relation is true and 0 if it is false.  The result has type int. 
>    For any pair of operands, exactly one of the relations is true.

So here as `b+c` is equal to `a` as both has value `10` therefore it yields `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Because b + c is executed first, and after is evaluate comparison with == operator.

Answer (score 0):

In c, addition has higher precedence than `==`, so it adds  b and c before comparing the result to a, since it is true it results in 1, if it was false it would result in 0.

Answer (score 0):

`==` is the equal-to operator. It returns `1` if the two sides are equal and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Even in C11 `==` [returns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18098119/11683) an `int`, not `bool`.