# Return types of operator == in C

Tags: c, types, misra

What is the return type of any operator ?
How to determine it?
Is it platform dependent ?

This question popped up while I was doing MISRA code compliance for as I was
required to typecast the parameters of the if keyword like this

```
if((bool_t)(cmd <= 1)){}
```

to appease lint of the 14.4 MISRA required guideline.
can you point me to some documentation regarding operator return type ?
If anyone can find out the documentation for the return types of the
 operators please post it here as it will be of great help for people
 referring hereafter.

Comment: the return type for comparisions in c is `int` (because there is no bool). look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097922/return-value-of-operator-in-c

Comment: IMO a coding standard that requires that cast inside an `if` should be thrown away. That just reduces readability.

Comment: The core language rules describe the types and values of the expressions in the language. Relational expressions have type `int`; the type of arithmetic expressions depends on the operand types and is determined by a somewhat non-trivial set of promotion and conversion rules.

Comment: From a pure practicability point of view: The result type of boolean operators is the very type that conditional statements expect. Going by the "never use type casting where not required" rule adding an explicit cast there is reason enough to completely ignore that coding standard.

Comment: @x4rf41 In C, there is a boolean type: `_Bool` since C99.  That type though did not exist at the time of C's formation.

Comment: Posting the true code that generated the MISRA code compliance issue and the exact  MISRA statement would be useful.  Only code posted here is the "fix".  The MISRA guideline is missing too.

Comment: Why the down votes. This question is yet to be covered on SO and it will be a huge help for guys who might face the same difficulty in the future. I was hoping upvotes for the same.

Comment: Please specify which MISRA standard this is about. I'm assuming MISRA-C:2012?

Comment: Regarding down votes, broad questions ("what is the return type of any operator") are generally frowned upon. And questions asking for external resources like documentation, libraries, tools etc are off-topic. If you had narrowed down this question to just be about why you are getting the warning from Lint, it would have been the perfect format for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Return types of operator == in C

... The result has type `int`. ...  C11dr Equality operators §6.5.9 3

> What is the return type of any operator ?

Sometimes it depend on the operator and the operands

```
a*b --> result type could be `int`, `double`, etc.
```

Others, it is fixed.

```
a==b --> result type is `int`.
```

> How to determine it?

1. By code analysis - you or a static analyzer looks at the code.
2. At run time, use `_Generic()`

The following handles many situations.

```
#define typenameX(X) _Generic((X), \
_Bool: "_Bool", \
signed char: "signed char", \
char: "char", \
unsigned char: "unsigned char", \
short: "short", \
unsigned short: "unsigned short", \
int: "int", \
unsigned: "unsigned", \
long: "long", \
unsigned long: "unsigned long", \
long long: "long long", \
unsigned long long: "unsigned long long", \
float: "float", \
double: "double", \
long double: "long double", \
_Complex float: "_Complex float", \
_Complex double: "_Complex double", \
_Complex long double: "_Complex long double", \
void *: "void *", \
char *: "char *", \
const char *: "const char *", \
default: "other" \
)

int main(void) {
  double a = 2.0;
  puts(typenameX(a));
  puts(typenameX(a==4.0));
  short b;
  puts(typenameX(b));
  puts(typenameX(b*1));
  puts(typenameX(sizeof(b)));
  double cmd;
  puts(typenameX(cmd <= 1));
}
```

Output

```
double
int
short
int
unsigned long
int
```

> Is it platform dependent ?

With `cmd <= 1`, the return type in C is `int` - "platform independent".

The result type of `((int)i) * 123456` is "platform dependent".  It could be `int` or `long` for example.

> can you point me to some documentation regarding operator return type ?

In the case of `if((bool_t)(cmd <= 1)){}`, the result type of `cmd <= 1` is `int`.  C11 §6.5.8 6.  The `bool_t` is not needed when compiling in C.  Since the result type may differ in other languages (or with a non-compliant C compiler), code that needs to compile in more than one language may benefit by the cast.

The best document regarding operator return type is the (latest) C spec.

---

The concerns about "required to typecast the parameters of the `if` keyword" comes into play in arcane situations.  The result of a compare in C is **not** one of them.

C well defines the result of `if(expression)` to be "if the expression compares unequal to 0.".  C11dr §6.8.4.1 2

A **non-compliant** compiler may convert floating-point or a wide integer to an `int` first and *then* test against zero. `if((bool_t)x)` fixes that.

```
unsigned long long w = 0x800000000000u;
if (w) {

double x = 4294967296.0; // 0x1 0000 0000
if (x) {

double y = 0.123;
if (y) {
```

Handling of [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) is problematic.    OTOH, C does not well define how NaN compares to 0.  IEEE 758 does well define it and many C implementations follow that.  I do not see casting to `(bool_t)` helps in this case as it is equally lose concerning NaN.

```
double z = 0.0/0.0; // z is NaN;
if (z) {

if (!z) {
```

In early C++, there was no boolean either.  A user defined object, (but not `double`, `float`, pointers), was converted to `int` for the `if()`.   An arithmetic class (e.g. effecting a 256 integer) would have trouble should a non-zero value convert to `int 0`.  Using `!!` solved that.

```
myint256 a = foo();
if (!!a) {
```

Note: If a compiler does not have a true boolean type, then `(bool_t)` being maybe some integer type, will certainly foul code, much like above.

Comment: Please note that `bool_t` is a MISRA-C:2012 construct that they for some reason use in all their examples. The standard C boolean type is `_Bool`, the compiler is required to implement it. The macro `bool` which expands to `_Bool` and is found in stdbool.h might not be mandatory to implement though, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

With `if(1){...}` the code in `{}` is executed

With `if(0){...}` the code in `{}` is not executed

The return type is `int` and equality/relational operators (==, <=, >=,...) in C return `1` for *true* and `0` for *false*

Answer (score 0):

> What is the return type of any operator ? How to determine it?

It depends on the operator. Normally, the result is the same type as the promoted operand(s). The "logical" operators (comparison operators and `&& || !`) behave differently, because they return `int`, for historical reasons, because back in the days, C didn't have a bool type.

MISRA-C:2012 rule 14.4 requires that the contents of an `if` statement should be "essentially boolean".  The meaning of this is explained in detail in the MISRA document, but roughly it means that you should pretend that C has a bool type built in, and pretend that the result of the above mentioned operators is actually `bool`. This leads to increased readability and also significantly increased type safety during static analysis.

`if((bool_t)(cmd <= 1)){}` is however nonsense, the return type of the expression `cmd <= 1` is already *essentially boolean*. There is no need for a cast. If Lint gave you a warning, then there is a bug in Lint, file a bug report.

MISRA compilant code would look like:

```
if(cmd <= 1)
```

or

```
if(cmd <= 1u)
```

---

> can you point me to some documentation regarding operator return type ?

Chapter 6.5 of the C standard. It is on case-by-case basis. Roughly:

- Operators used to access an element (such as `[]`, unary `*`, unary `&`, `->`) returns the type of that element.
- Assignment operators return the type of the left operand.
- The relational operators, the equality operators, and the `! && ||` operators return `int` with value `1` or `0`, you can regard them as boolean type.
- The shift operators return the type of the promoted left operand.
- All other operators return the type of the promoted/balanced operand(s), if applicable.