# C if statement comparing two integer variables to the same constant

Tags: c, if-statement, integer, constants, comparison-operators

I am trying to compare two integer variables to a same constant. Apparently in this case, both variables have the same default values. I tried to simplify the comparison statement like this:

```
if (po->app_tag == po->inst_id == 0)
   return 1;
```

It didn't work.

I had to code it like:

```
if ((po->app_tag == 0) && (po->inst_id == 0))
   return 1;
```

To make it work. Can anyone explain to me the difference between the two? Somehow I feel that C compiler should have a provision for this kind of syntax when it comes to comparison of two integer variables. I can be wrong asking for it.. :), but want to understand a reason.. Why am I wrong here.

Comment: Do you know which values the expression `a == b` can return?

Comment: When you compare a variable to the result of another comparison, you're comparing it to either 0 or 1, which likely is not what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097922/return-value-of-operator-in-c

Comment: @EugeneSh. yeah.. made a basic mistake...

Comment: @ChintanShah Woah... you are quick to respond...

Comment: Even quicker this time.. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to associativity of the `==` operator (it associates from left to right),

```
po->app_tag == po->inst_id == 0
```

is interpreted as:

```
(po->app_tag == po->inst_id) == 0
```

That's how the language is defined.

Using

```
(po->app_tag == 0) && (po->inst_id == 0)
```

fixes that problem by evaluating `po->app_tag == 0` and `po->inst_id == 0` independently and performing a boolean AND between those two.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence for more info on operator precedence and associativity.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation..!!

Answer (score 1):

`po->app_tag == po->inst_id == 0` will be interpreted as `(po->app_tag == po->inst_id) == 0` - that is, the thing that is being compared to `0` aren't the two variables individually, but the result of `po->app_tag == po->inst_id`. That operation will return a `1` if the two values are equal, and a `0` if they are not. In effect, then, `po->app_tag == po->inst_id == 0` is equivalent to `po->app_tag != po->inst_id`, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation..!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way C/C++ compiler works. A compare expression can compare only two variables. If you want more then this you will need to use the logical AND (`&&`) or OR (`||`) expression. If you want to compare a variable with more then two **const** values you can use the `switch` statement.