# distance from root to a node of a binary tree

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have to find the distance of a node of a binary tree from its root.
My solution is:

```
int distanceUtil(struct node* root, int x, int dist) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        if (root->data == x) {
            return dist;
        }
        return distanceUtil(root->left, x, dist + 1) || distanceUtil(root->right, x, dist + 1);
    }
}

int distance(struct node* root, int x) {
    return distanceUtil(root, x, 0);
}
```

but it does not work.In fact when in the main i do:

```
struct node* root = newNode(12);
root->left = newNode(8);
root->right = newNode(18);
root->left->left = newNode(2);
root->left->right = newNode(9);
root->right->left = newNode(15);
root->right->right = newNode(22);
root->right->right->right = newNode(33);
printf("il cammino : %d", distance(root,33));
getchar();
return 0;
```

it returns 1, but it should return 3. Can somebody help me? 
Thank's.

Comment: `||` only return either 0 or 1.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098119/3072566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the logical OR operator `||` to combine the results of searching the left tree and the right tree.  The results of the operator are always 0 or 1, so you won't get any result besides that.

What you really want is to return the larger of the two values of each subtree search.  So store the result of searching each side, then check which is larger and return that.

```
int distanceUtil(struct node* root, int x, int dist) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (root->data == x) {
        return dist;
    }

    int left = distanceUtil(root->left, x, dist + 1);
    int right = distanceUtil(root->right, x, dist + 1);
    if (left > right) {
        return left;
    } else {
        return right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add results of each side? He does not want to count all nodes!

Comment: @Klaus It works if 0 is returned when nothing is found.  However, that returns the same result as if the target value is in the root node.  I've updated with an alternate way that distinguishes between the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
int findDistance(Node *root,int key)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return 1e9;
    if(root->data==key)
        return 0;
    return 1+min(findDistance(root->left,key),findDistance(root->right,key));
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so the logic is clear to others reading. For example, what is the meaning of `1e9` as a sentinel, etc. It would help someone understand the recursion a bit better if explained.